# How to sort std::map by property value in struct

Tags: c++, dictionary, std

I have a struct like this...

```
struct MessageLetter{
 char letter;
 int count;
 MessageLetter() {}
 MessageLetter(char letter, int count)
 : letter(letter), count(count)
 {}
};
```

I use it to create the following map...

```
std::map<char, MessageLetter> lList;
```

I would like to sort it, something like this for a list...

```
bool compare_count(const MessageLetter& first, const MessageLetter& second){
  if(first.count > second.count){
   return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

How would I do this? Would I need to use something like...

```
bool compare_count(const std::pair <char,MessageLetter>& first, const const std::pair <char,MessageLetter>& second)
```

Comment: You can't sort a `map`, it maintains the order itself.

Answer (score 1):

You have a fairly basic problem here. An `std::map` is always sorted based on the *key* type (the first template parameter). You want sorting based on the *second* parameter (the value). That's simply not supported.

From the looks of things, what you're trying to do is to count up the frequencies of characters in a message, then write them out in descending order by frequency.

If so, you really need (or at least want) to do things in three steps: first count up the frequencies, *then* sort by frequency, and finally print out the sorted data.

For the first step, I'd just use a vector:

```
unsigned max = std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max();

std::vector<unsigned> counts(max);

while (infile >> ch)
    ++counts[(unsigned char)ch];
```

Then I'd probably copy that data to an `std::multimap<unsigned, char>` to get it sorted based on the count (and note we do want a `multimap` here, because we might have more than one `char` with the same count).

```
std::multimap<unsigned, char> frequencies;
typedef std::pair<unsigned, char> v_t;

for (unsigned char i=0; i<max; i++)
    frequencies.insert(std::make_pair(i, counts[i]));
```

Finally, write out the result in descending order by frequency:

```
std::copy(frequencies.rbegin(), frequencies.rend(), 
          std::ostream_iterator<v_t>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Comment: right so here you are creating a map with the frequency as key, therefore it sorts based on key correct?. I will look into this and see if I can use this instead. On my version I am still doing the 3 steps listed I am just caught on the second because instead of what you are doing I am using a map. Maybe the map is overkill and I can use a list. The hard part would be to determine if the collection already contains the letter, without the overhead of multiple iterations of said list. That was the point behind using the map. I am new to c++ so I will examine your part one and see if it works.

Comment: Also can you explain this a little more.. "while (infile >> ch)" I am assuming infile is the string.

Comment: Also does this store every char or just A-Z and a-z those are all I need and iterating through 300 or however many chars there are as opposed to 62 seems a bit extreme.

Comment: @Jackie: Yes, this stores all (typically 256) characters. If you only need letters, that's pretty easy to handle as well (though it's generally easy to just count everything, and only print out letters). The `while (infile >> ch)` assumes reading from a file, but changing to read from a string is trivial.

Comment: As for whether the first part works: Of *course* it works! Everything I post works! If it doesn't you either misunderstood your question, or else I was intentionally leaving something for you as an exercise. Couldn't possibly be that I made a mistake, anyway. :-)